# Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.Base.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, web-component

I have created a web-component with different dependencies, among them is iron-icon component powered by Polymer.

However, when I deploy my component I see the next message in the console:

"Uncaught TypeError: Polymer.Base.create is not a function" in the iron-icon.html file, line 142.

To install the dependencies of the proyect I have used the next bower.json:

```
    {
      "name": "facebook-wall",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "keywords": [
        "polymer",
        "web-components",
        "facebook",
        "wall",
        "facebook-wall"
      ],
      "main": "facebook-wall.html",
      "dependencies": {
        "iron-ajax": "PolymerElements/iron-ajax",
        "paper-header-panel": "PolymerElements/paper-header-panel",
        "paper-styles": "PolymerElements/paper-styles",
        "iron-icon": "PolymerElements/iron-icon",
        "iron-icons": "PolymerElements/iron-icons",
        "paper-icon-button": "PolymerElements/paper-icon-button",
        "paper-material": "PolymerElements/paper-material",
        "paper-button": "PolymerElements/paper-button",
        "web-component-tester": "Polymer/web-component-tester#~4.2.1",
        "test-fixture": "PolymerElements/test-fixture#^1.0.0",
        "paper-behaviors": "PolymerElements/paper-behaviors#~1.0.12"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "polymer-test-tools": "Polymer/polymer-test-tools#master",
        "mocha": "~1.14.0",
        "sinon": "http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-1.10.2.js"
      },
      "resolutions": {
        "mocha": "^2.3.0"
      },
      "authors": [
        "Miguel Ortega Moreno <miguel.ortega.moreno5@gmail.com>"
      ],
      "description": "Polymer component which show a facebook wall",
      "moduleType": [],
      "license": "MIT",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/Mortega5/facebook-wall",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "test",
        "tests",
        "*.*~"
      ]
   }
```

Do you know what is wrong with it?

Comment: Maybe the file where Polymer.Base.create is defined is missing. Do you have Network error in the console. Is Polymer.html present?

Comment: No, the Polymer.html is present, but the function is not defined. I have seen it now, but the key is the element where the error is has been developed by the Polymer team.

Comment: I opened an issue in its Github repository, but I don't know if they are use to answer.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall all dependencies using boxer install --force ?

Comment: Yes, and I install the latest version of the element.

Comment: Please do not change your question into an answer. Instead, summarise the fix in an answer below. Would you do that when you next sign on, please? I have rolled back the [solved] edit - we do not mark the tile as solved either here. Remember that answers with no corresponding question are not useful for future readers, and the whole point of Stack Overflow is create useful question-answer pairs. Thanks.

Comment: The problem has been solved. The change made was force to install a certain version of iron-icon component, which was the origin of the problem. I forced it to install version 1.0.5, which can be done in this way:
`"iron-icon": "PolymerElements/iron-icon#~1.0.5",`
in the bower.json of your component. It will install the latest version of this component.